# Trouble creating string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a script as follows where **element** is a number:

```
function updateList(element) {
    var out_list = "<Select name='item" + element + "' onchange=getQualType(this.value, 'qualType" + element + "')>";
.... add options here ...
    out_list += "</Select>"
    document.getElementById('dropdown_list' + element).innerHTML = out_list;
}
```

However what is in the browser is:

```
<select name="item40" onchange="getQualType(this.value," 'qualtype40')="">
</script>
```

Can anyone point out what is causing the incorrect quotes in the output?

UPDATE

Spotted it:

```
    var out_list = "<Select name='item" + element + "' onchange=getQualType(this.value, 'qualType" + element + "')'>";
```

Single quote after bracket - thanks all.

Comment: This should work just fine.

Comment: The JS isn't "wrong" as to the `select` it's output, per se. Its writing out your `select` element *literally* (and thus, correctly). Your string that creates it is technically the issue. You could just create a handler for the `select` through JS, and handle the `onchange` event that way, instead :)

Comment: no error in this...its fine

Comment: Just spotted it - missed quote after the bracket!!

Comment: you have to put quotes around the onchange-script. this way, it can't contains any spaces, like the one before `'qualType" + element + "'`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, you had problems at escaping quotes:

```
var out_list = '<select name="item' + element + '" onchange="getQualType(this.value, \'qualType' + element + '\')">';
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by quoting the `onChange`. If you don't do it, the browser makes its own decisions:

```
 var out_list = "<Select name='item" + element + "' onchange=\"getQualType(this.value, 'qualType" + element + "');\">";
```